# Multi-texture drawing with OpenGL?

Tags: c, opengl

I am trying to draw with OpenGL some object with 2 or more different texture. for example 3 sprites from 3 different spritesheets.
you can see  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5jV7.jpg)  what I expected and what I have
The problem I have now is that all sprites are from the 1 spritesheet.
let have a look, first in the initialisation i load 3 images img0,img1,img2

```
img0 = loadSurface2D("image0.png");
img1 = loadSurface2D("image1.png");
img2 = loadSurface2D("image2.png");
```

then in my draw loop a little bit like SDL2:

```
BKP_Rec dest,src;                                                                                                                    
g2D_renderSurface(img0,NULL,NULL);//will draw all the sprite sheet a (0,0)

src.x = 0;
src.y = 4;
src.w = 64;
src.h = 64;
dest.x = 512;
dest.y = 300;
dest.w = 128;
dest.h = 128;
g2D_renderSurface(img1,&dest,&src);//draw sprite(0,4) 

src.x = 1;
src.y = 2;
dest.x = 562;
dest.y = 300;

g2D_renderSurface(img2,&dest,&src);//draw img 2 sprite(1,2)
```

let have a look at loadSurface2D

```
Surface2D * loadSurface2D(const char * file)
{
    unsigned  int width, height;
    unsigned char * image = image_loadPNG(file,&width,&height);
    //...all test & flip image are done here, removed it for lisibility
    Surface2D * s = NULL;
    ALLOC_L(Surface2D, s, 1);

    s->data = image;

    s->point[0]  = 0; s->point[1] = 0 ; s->point[2] = 0; s->point[3] = 1;
    s->point[4]  = 0; s->point[5] = -nh; s->point[6] = 0; s->point[7] = 1;
    s->point[8]  = nw; s->point[9] = -nh ; s->point[10] = 0; s->point[11] = 1;
    s->point[12] = nw; s->point[13] = 0 ; s->point[14] = 0; s->point[15] = 1;

    s->texture[0]   = 0.0f; s->texture[1]  = 1.0f ;
    s->texture[2]   = 0.0f; s->texture[3]  = 0.0f;
    s->texture[4]   = 1.0f; s->texture[5]  = 0.0f ;
    s->texture[6]   = 1.0f; s->texture[7]  = 1.0f ;

    s->w = (GLfloat) width;
    s->h = (GLfloat) height;

    bkp_numcal_setIdentity4(s->Mtx_translate);
    bkp_numcal_setIdentity4(s->Mtx_scale);
    bkp_numcal_setIdentity4(s->Mtx_rotate);
    bkp_numcal_setIdentity4(s->Mtx_i);
    bkp_numcal_setIdentity4(s->Mtx);

    GLuint point_vbo = 0;
    glGenBuffers(1,&point_vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, point_vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(s->point),s->point,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint tex_vbo = 1;
    glGenBuffers(1,&tex_vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tex_vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(s->texture),s->texture,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint vao = stc_2d->vao_num;
    stc_2d->vao_num += 1;
    glGenVertexArrays(1,&vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, point_vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,4,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,NULL);

    GLuint dimension = 2;
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tex_vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1,dimension,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,NULL);

    s->sampler_loc = glGetUniformLocation(stc_2d->sh_sprite, "basic_texture");
    s->texunit_id = GL_TEXTURE0 + stc_2d->texunit_id;
    stc_2d->texunit_id += 1; // initialized at 0, every function call it increments

    GLuint tex = stc_2d->tex_num;
    ++stc_2d->tex_num;  // same here, another global at 0 when initialized
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glUseProgram(stc_2d->sprite); // EDITED
    glUniform1i(s->sampler_loc, s->texunit_id);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,
        GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    int st_offset_loc = glGetUniformLocation(stc_2d->sh_sprite, "vt_");
    glUniformMatrix2fv(st_offset_loc, 1,GL_FALSE, s->vt_);
    s->st_offset = st_offset_loc;

    s->vt_[0] = 0.0;
    s->vt_[1] = 0.0;
    s->vt_[2] = 0.0;
    s->vt_[3] = 0.0;

    s->vao = vao;
    s->texid = tex;
    s->tex_vbo = tex_vbo;
    s->point_vbo = point_vbo;
    return s;
}
```

Basically I just load the png create the texture. there is some values (stc_2D->*) initialized at 0 when starting that behave at counter ex: stc_2D->vba_num telling the current vba number to create.

now the function to render

```
void g2D_renderSurface(BKP_Surface2D * s,BKP_Rec * dest,BKP_Rec * src)
{
    glUseProgram(stc_2d->sh_sprite);
    glBindVertexArray(s->vao);

    glActiveTexture(s->texunit_id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, s->texid);
    //glUniform1i(s->sampler_loc, s->texunit_id);
```

Let assume I didn't comment this line

```
    float xf,yf;

    if(dest != NULL)
    {
        xf = (dest->x / (float) stc_fb_width * 2 - 1) ;
        yf = - ((dest->y / (float) stc_fb_height * 2 - 1));
        bkp_numcal_setFreeScalMatrix4(s->Mtx_scale,dest->w /s->w, dest->h/ s->h, 1.0f);
    }
    else
    {
        xf =  - 1 ;
        yf =   1;
        bkp_numcal_setIdentity4(s->Mtx_scale);
    }

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);

    if(src != NULL)
    {
        s->vt_[0] =(float)(src->x * src->w) / s->w;
        s->vt_[1] = (float) src->w / s->w;
        s->vt_[2] =(s->h - (float)((1 + src->y) * src->h) )/ s->h;
        s->vt_[3] = (float) src->h / s->h;
    }
    else
    {
        s->vt_[0] = 0.0;
        s->vt_[1] = (float) s->w / s->w;
        s->vt_[2] = 0.0;
        s->vt_[3] = (float) s->h / s->h;
    }

    glUniform4fv(s->st_offset,1,s->vt_);

    bkp_numcal_translate4(s->Mtx_translate, xf, yf, 0);
    bkp_numcal_multMat4Mat4(s->Mtx,s->Mtx_scale,s->Mtx_translate);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(stc_2d->mtx_location, 1,GL_FALSE, s->Mtx);
    return;
}
```

Now at the end the shaders.

vertex:

```
#version 410\n
in vec3 vertex_position;uniform mat4 matrix;
in vec2 vt_loc;
varying vec2 v_uv;
uniform vec4 vt_;
void main() 
{
    v_uv.x = (vt_loc.x * vt_[1]) + vt_[0];
    v_uv.y = (vt_loc.y * vt_[3]) + (vt_[2]);

    gl_Position = matrix * vec4(vertex_position, 1.0);
 }
```

fragment:

```
#version 410
out vec4 frag_colour;
uniform sampler2D basic_texture;
varying vec2 v_uv;
void main() 
{
    vec4 texel = texture(basic_texture, v_uv);
    frag_colour = texel; 
}
```

I think they is probably something I don't understand, as I don't see why it will draw 3 object the size i want, the position I want but with the only same texture. I was thinking I overwrite the same texture but it is the first texture that is shown not the last one loaded.

Comment: The value for the sampler uniform `basic_texture` has to be 0, 1, 2, ... and **not** '`GL_TEXTURE0`, `GL_TEXTURE1`, `GL_TEXTURE2`, .... See my answer

Comment: People know they subject. So now it works. I still have some other issues as it does display the 3 images but texture are not at the good object but that basically I have the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: For the record this is what I changed. In loadsurface. S->texunit_id = stc_2D->texunit_id.    And in render as suggested glActivateTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + s->texunit_id); glUniform1i(s->sampler_loc, s->texunit_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`glUniform*`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) specifies the value of a uniform variable for the **current** program object.
[`glUseProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUseProgram.xhtml) installs a program object as part of current rendering state.

The last value which is set by `glUniform*` is stored. Remove all settings of uniform values from `loadSurface2D`. Do all settings of uniform values in `g2D_renderSurface` right after `glUseProgram(stc_2d->sh_sprite);`.

Futher note, the value which you have to assign to the texture sampler uniform  `basic_texture` is, **not the texture unit enumeration constant** (**not `GL_TEXTURE0`, `GL_TEXTURE1`, ...**).
It has to be the **number of the texture unit (0, 1, 2. ...)**.

This is wrong:

```
s->texunit_id = GL_TEXTURE0 + stc_2d->texunit_id;
glUniform1i(s->sampler_loc, s->texunit_id);
```

It has to be:

```
s->texunit_id = stc_2d->texunit_id;

.....

glUseProgram(stc_2d->sh_sprite);

glActiveTexture(s->texunit_id + GL_TEXTURE0); // GL_TEXTURE0, GL_TEXTURE1, GL_TEXTURE2, ....
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, s->texid);
glUniform1i(s->sampler_loc, s->texunit_id);   // 0, 1, 2, ....
```

Comment: Yes, but that is not the issue, in fact I have glUseProgram(stc_2d->sprite); I didn't copy correctly, let me edit it to not distract people.

Comment: You call `glUseProgram(stc_2d->sprite);` before `loadSurface2D`?

Comment: Not before, in loadSurface2D, just after glBindTexture()

Answer (score 0):

Uniforms in a shader always store the last state they are set to. Since you change the active texture before drawing, you also have to update the sampler uniform (the line is already there, not sure why its a comment).

```
glActiveTexture(s->texunit_id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, s->texid);
glUniform1i(s->sampler_loc, s->texunit_id); //<-- This is important
```

Comment: I commented it because  it didn't change anything,  I was just trying without it.

Comment: I edited it but kept the comments as you marked it as important.  I commented it just to try what will happen without it. But nothing changed. In my code I will uncomment it. But keep it like this here for other readers